# Issue with saving validation rules to a configuration file

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

I am trying to move validation rules from a controller into a configuration file.  I am following the directions as documented [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig), but I can't get it to work.  When the form is submitted, the validation doesn't execute.  Echoing `validation_errors()` prints nothing.

After doing a little digging, the `run()` method in the form validation library is returning *false* because there are no configuration rules set.  Here is an excerpt:

**system/libraries/Form_validation.php:**

```
// No validation rules?  We're done...
if (count($this->_config_rules) == 0)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my code:

**application/controllers/signup.php:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Signup extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->user_model->insert(array(
                'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            ));

            redirect('/log-in');
        }

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('signup/index');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}

/* End of file signup.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/signup.php */
```

**application/config/form_validation.php:**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
    'signup/index' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'email_address',
            'label' => 'Email Address',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[255]|valid_email|email_in_use'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'confirm_password',
            'label' => 'Confirm Password',
            'rules' => 'required|matches[password]'
        ),
    ),
);

/* End of file form_validation.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/form_validation.php */
```

I am using CI 2.1.0.

Comment: i got the same pro...Is this a bug?

Comment: it seems like someone face the same pro as before.you can find some solutions in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179936/custom-config-file-not-working-with-form-validation?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your config var in the run method. Read the section in your posted link called "Calling a Specific Rule Group".

Comment: The documentation states that "when a rule group is named identically to a controller class/function it will be used automatically when the `run()` function is invoked from that class/function."  I shouldn't have to pass the config key into the `run()` method, although it still doesn't work when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a typo by your side there, but configuration should be store inside `application/config/form_validation.php` (and not "application/controllers/signup.php" as you wrote in the post).
This way it should be called automatically.

Expanding on what @Catfish said, you can either:

1. Don't create a different set of rules (if you need just one), and your array'll look like:

   ```
   $config = array(
              array(
                    'field'   => 'username',
                    'label'   => 'Username',
                    'rules'   => 'required'
                 ),
              array(
   ```
2. Create different sets of rules, which follows the structure you have used; but in this case, you need to pass to the `run()` method *which* rule you want to use. So, in your case, it should be

   ```
     if($this->form->validation->run('signup/index'))
   ```

Comment: I'm going to need multiple sets of rules, although it still doesn't work if there is only one.  Also, passing the the rule to the `run()` method results in the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

Have you loaded the form_validation library in `config/autoload.php`? Because I don't see it being loaded in your controller. If you want to load it in your controller use `$this->load->library('form_validation')`.

I see a rule for the email field called `email_in_use`, Where is this rule stored? If you are going to create custom rules, make sure it is in `libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`.

I have never used the controller/function method, and it has always worked for me. I would use something like `$this->form_validation->run('login');` for something like this.

Can you confirm whether the validation `run()` call is evaluating to true or false? Is your page redirecting to *log-in*? (BTW: I don't think you need the `/` in the redirect call.

Lastly, do you have PHP errors turned on to E_ALL? Check `php.ini`.